# Sympy dot product does not read dimensions correctly

Tags: python, sympy

I want to multiply two matrices in `sympy`. However, the `.dot()` function does not seem to work properly, as when using the transpose matrix so that the dimensions match, the same error appears as when not using it.

Code to reproduce:

```
from sympy import *
x1, x2, x3 = symbols('x1 x2 x3')

x = Matrix([x1, x2, x3])
m = Matrix([1, 2, 3])
xm = (x-m)
print(xm.shape)
xmt = xm.T
print(xmt.shape)
c = Matrix([[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 4], [3, 4, 5]])
print(c.shape)
```

Output:

```
(3, 1)
(1, 3)
(3, 3)
```

Now, whether you try

```
xm.dot(c)
```

or

```
xmt.dot(c)
```

**Both** commands result in the same error:

```
ShapeError: Matrix size mismatch: (3, 1) * (3, 3).
```

which shouldn't be possible, since `xm` matrix is indeed of dimensions (3,1) but `xmt` is of dimensions (1,3).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like you shouldn't assume this `sympy` `dot` works the same as the `numpy` one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems like a bug in sympy, but using `dot` is already deprecated, use the `@` operator for matrix dot product and it will work

```py
result = xmt @ c
```

you could post an issue on sympy's github about `dot`, but you shouldn't be using it anyway, as it is deprecated.

**Edit:** according to @hpaulj the correct function to call in sympy would be `xmt.multiply(c)` if the `@` operator is to be avoided.

Comment: Thanks! Can you post me a documentation link about this operator?

Comment: this is its pep page https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/

Comment: `xm.dot` docs says it's the `inner product` of vectors.  So in contrast to `numpy.dot` it has not been generalized to matrix multiplication.   `xmt.multiply(c)` works.  Since `xmt` is `Matrix`, not `ndarray`, `xmt*c` also works.  But due to the possible confusion with `multiply_elementwise`, `@` may be preferred.